# cocos2d-x zlib support is missing crypt.c

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x, zlib

I just noticed that the zlib_support in cocos2d-x is missing crypt.c

I was able to update the code and add crypt.h from

http://programming-practice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/LevelUp/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.11.0/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/marmalade/zlib/contrib/minizip/crypt.h

to the project to get it working but I would like to know why this functionality is removed from the framework in the first place? Is there an alternative to the crypt.h I have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the reason.

When you go on to publish your app, you are required to disclose if you are using encryption or not. And if your answer is yes, then there are separate and significantly longer process of approval. Adding encryption into cocos2d-x would therefore result in long approval times for a large number of apps. Hence it's not included.

http://cheminf20.org/2011/08/29/releasing-an-ios-app-using-encryption-first-time/